# Mobile phone (iPhone, Windows CE, Symbian, Android) search engines (text indexers)?

Tags: mobile, full-text-search, search-engine, mobile-phones, full-text-indexing

I'm looking for search engines that will run on one or more of the mobile platforms listed in the title.

Something like Lucene (which '[should](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/601329551a87e601/cd0919ce891b4a26?lnk=gst&q=lucene)' run on Android) or [minion](https://minion.dev.java.net/).

What are my alternatives on each platform? Have you made them run? What are the limitations you stumbled upon (cannot index more than 20 megs, for example)?

Answer (score 0):

There are some smaller and lighter Java search engines, that might be the way to go.

And now I'm fascinated: if you could, please tell me more about what you want to index and search on a mobile phone. Personal data? Cached html pages?  Recipes?

Comment: Any particular recommendation? I'm interested in searching local html pages, yes.